# C# Add TimeSpan to DateTime by considering BusinessDays

Tags: c#

I have a collection of dates that are business days and I have a Start Date. When I add a `TimeSpan` to the Start Date `DateTime` I have to ensure that when adding the days in `TimeSpan`, I skip over holidays. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by holidays? Weekends? Bank holidays? Your trip to Spain?

Comment: I specified that I have a collection of dates that I treat as business days

Comment: Yep and you also specified that you want to skip over holidays, but you haven't specified what you mean by 'holidays'?

Comment: Anything not in the collection is a holiday

Comment: if you already have the collection of business days what is stopping you, can you elaborate.. its too vague

Comment: Well, the method I can think of is get TimeSpan.Days, verify for holidays and add it to StartDate. Then create a new timespan with the same hours, minutes and seconds and add it to the date. Is there something that isn't so roundabout?

Comment: @Aks In short you would be adding same hours mins sec timespan as much as the number of items in the collection ...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
public DateTime AddBusinessDays(List<DateTime> businessDays, DateTime startDate, TimeSpan span)
{
    // Add the initial timespan
    DateTime endDate = startDate.Add(span);

    // Calculate the number of holidays by taking off the number of business days during the period
    int noOfHolidays = span.Days - businessDays.Where(d => d >= startDate && d <= endDate).Count();

    // Add the no. of holidays found
    endDate.AddDays(noOfHolidays);

    // Skip the end date if it lands on a holiday
    while (businessDays.Contains(endDate))
        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);

    return endDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the timespan as it is. When that is done, you iterate search for dates in your collection that falls between the original date and the new date. For each time you encounter for each hit you add another day to the new date, and repeat until you are through your collection of dates. This can be optimized if your datecollection is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account how many non-business days there are in any added date range.

In a 20 day range, there may be 6 non-business days. 
You can't just add this number of days to the last day because the new date range may contain non-business days too. You have to add the days, and then figure out how many of those days you've added are also holidays:

Here's some non-tested pcode

```
Add Timespan to date (DateIn,timespan)
    finalDateTime = (fromDate + timespan)

    fromDate = DateIn.date  
    toDate = finalDateTime.date 

    repeat 
        iDays = GetHolidaysBetween (fromDate, toDate) 
        finalDateTime = (finalDateTime + iDays) 

        fromDate = (toDate+1)   
        toDate = (toDate+iDays) 
    until (iDays=0)

    return finalDateTime
end_function
```